# PyTorch Broadcasting Failing. "Rules" Followed

Tags: python, numpy, torch, pytorch

I have a few PyTorch examples that confuse me and am hoping to clear it up.

Firstly, as per the PyTorch page, I would expect these example to work as do their numpy equivalents namely [these](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html). The first example is very intuitive. These are compatible for broadcasting:

```
Image  (3d array): 256 x 256 x 3
Scale  (1d array):             3
Result (3d array): 256 x 256 x 3
```

Take for instance these:

```
torch.Tensor([[1,2,3]])/torch.Tensor([1,2,3])
Out[5]: 

 1  1  1
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x3]
torch.Tensor([[1,2,3]])/torch.Tensor([1,2,3])
Out[6]: 

  1  1  1
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x3]

torch.Tensor([[[1,2,3]]])/torch.Tensor([1,2,3])
Out[7]: 

(0 ,.,.) = 
  1  1  1
[torch.FloatTensor of size 1x1x3]
```

However, this is the result of the numpy example:

```
torch.randn(256,256,3)/torch.Tensor([1,2,3])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-12-4c328d453e24>", line 1, in <module>
    torch.randn(256,256,3)/torch.Tensor([1,2,3])

  File "/home/nick/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/tensor.py", line 313, in __div__
    return self.div(other)

RuntimeError: inconsistent tensor size at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1501971235237/work/pytorch-0.1.12/torch/lib/TH/generic/THTensorMath.c:873
```

[Here is an excerpt which says this ought to work:](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/notes/broadcasting.html)

> Two tensors are “broadcastable” if the following rules hold:
>
> 1. Each tensor has at least one dimension.
> 2. **When iterating over the dimension sizes, starting at the trailing dimension, the dimension sizes must either be equal**, one of them is 1, or one of them does not exist.

If one converts the tensors to numpy arrays the arithmetic works as expected.

What's going wrong? Have I misinterpreted the docs and if so what syntax results in the same results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Verify that you are using the correct version of pytorch. It must be 0.2.0, which is when broadcasting was introduced in pytorch.

```
In[2]: import torch
In[3]: torch.__version__

Out[3]: '0.2.0_4'
```